# Descending chain condition on finitely generated (left/right) ideals and coherent rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Does anyone know of any interesting results on the descending chain condition for finitely generated (left/right) ideals in a unital ring, especially for coherent rings. In particular are there any generalisations of the Hopkins-Levitzki theorem?

I'd be happy for pointers to things in the literature.

Comment: Isn't DCC on f.g. right ideals the same thing as being right or left perfect? If so, I think you'd have an easier time with that keyword.

Comment: Oh, ok i think I found what i was remembering.  The condition "f.g. submodules of all right $R$ modules satisfy DCC" is equivalent to $R$ being left perfect.

Comment: So a left perfect ring satisfies DCC on f.g. right ideals. Conversely satisfying DCC on f.g. on the f.g. right ideals would ensure DCC on right principal ideals, which implies the ring is left perfect.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. In fact I found some stuff in Lam's Non-Commutative Rings that covered this topic well.